# Modify CSS parameters of Breadcrumb leaf with ngClass in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, breadcrumbs, ng-class

I am developing a Breadcrumb component in Angular which will show the complete address about the routing. Helping the user to go back to any step it was before. To get the actual url I am using [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute). It works fine.

My question is about set different class to the last element using this example style of [Breadcrumb](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/breadcrumb/). (Bootstrap 4) Which shows different style on the last element of the routing. (Data using **active** and **aria-current="page"**)

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/library">Library</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Data</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

To get the last element of the list and set different CSS class I am using this [example](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-ngfor/):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let last = last" [ngClass]="{last: last}">{{item.path}}</li>
```

But I can not achieve the objective of enable class="active" and aria-current="page" using the css file which looks like:

```
.last{
  // I do not know how to enable from here active and arria-current
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieved. It is not necessary to use active class.

Using **pointer-event** you can disable the option to click the link using CSS class.

> HTML

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let last = last" [ngClass]="{last: last}">{{item.path}}</li>
```

> CSS

```
.last a{
    color: grey;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```